# Envio formulario email sin refrescar php y ajax

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, ajax

Tengo el siguiente código con el cual lo que quiero es enviar un email (eso funciona correctamente) sin que tenga que refrescar la página y ademas que un div que tengo con un display none cambie a flex. Las dos cosas por separado me funcionan, el fallo es al querer hacerlo todo junto, que lo que ocurre es que el div se muestra pero el mensaje no se envia. Espero vuestra ayuda, un saludo!

```
   <!--form without refreshing (ajax)-->
<script>
    function chk(){
        require_once('js/addcampos.php'); //aqui realizo el envio del mensaje

        var dataModal = document.getElementById('modalSuccess');

        $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url:"<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>",
            cache:false,
            success: function(){
                $("#modalSuccess").css("display","flex");
                $("form")[0].reset();
                setTimeout("$('#modalSuccess').hide();", 3000);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
</script>

<div id="formulario-email">
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Introduce tu email" id="email"><br>
<input type="text" name="asunto" placeholder="Introduce el asunto del mensaje" id="asunto"><br>
<textarea name="mensaje" id="mensaje" placeholder="Introduce el cuerpo del mensaje" cols="30" rows="6"></textarea>
<input type="submit" onclick="return chk()" name="enviar" value="Enviar">
</form>
</div>

<div id="modalSuccess">
    <span>Mensaje enviado correctamente</span>
</div>

</div>

</div>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['asunto']) && isset($_POST['mensaje']) && isset($_POST['email'])) {

        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $mensaje = $_POST['mensaje'];
        $asunto = $_POST['asunto'];

        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers = "Content-type: text/html: charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
        $headers = "From:$email";

        $bool = mail("oplumariegadev@gmail.com",$asunto,$mensaje,$headers);

        if ($bool) {
            header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
        }

    }else{
        echo "Falta algo";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: intenta sacar el `require_once` fuera del `script`

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto

```
 <div id="formulario-email">
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" id="form">
       <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Introduce tu email" id="email"><br>
       <input type="text" name="asunto" placeholder="Introduce el asunto del mensaje" id="asunto"><br>
       <textarea name="mensaje" id="mensaje" placeholder="Introduce el cuerpo del mensaje" cols="30" rows="6"></textarea>
       <input type="submit" onclick="return chk(event)" name="enviar" value="Enviar">
     </form>
 </div>
       <div id="modalSuccess">
          <span>Mensaje enviado correctamente</span>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>

    function chk(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var dataModal = document.getElementById('modalSuccess');
        var form = document.querySelector('#form');

        $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url:"rutadearchivoqueenviacorreo.php",
            cache:false,
            data : form.serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response){

                if(response.enviado){

                    $("#modalSuccess").css("display","flex");
                    $("form")[0].reset();
                    setTimeout("$('#modalSuccess').hide();", 3000);
                }

            }
        });
        return false;
    }

</script>



 <?php

 if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
   if (isset($_POST['asunto']) && isset($_POST['mensaje']) && isset($_POST['email'])) {

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $mensaje = $_POST['mensaje'];
    $asunto = $_POST['asunto'];

    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers = "Content-type: text/html: charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    $headers = "From:$email";

    $bool = mail("oplumariegadev@gmail.com",$asunto,$mensaje,$headers);


    $enviado = $bool ? true : false;

    return json_encode([
        'enviado' => $enviado
    ]);


  }else{
     echo "Falta algo";
 }
}

?>
```

Comment: nada, no hace ninguna accion el submit...